# Prove $A_m$ is closed in $C[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology

Let $m\in\mathbb{N}$ arbitrary and $A_m \subset C[0,1]$, the subset of all function $f$ verify: Exists $x_0\in[0,1-\frac{1}{m}]$ such that: $\frac{f(x_0+h-f(x_0)}{h}\leq m \forall h\in(0,\frac{1}{m}$

Prove $A_m$ is closed in $C[0,1]$

My idea is:

Prove $A_m$ is bounded uniformly and equicontinuous then by Ascoli theorem $A_m$ be compact.

This implies $A_m$ is closed set.

But i don't know how to prove this, can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean that $A_m$ is the set of all functions in $\mathcal{C}[0, 1]$ which satisfy the condition "exists $x_0 \in [0, 1-\frac{1}{m}]$ such that..." ?

Comment: Yes @Adayah is that

Comment: Given the attempt you used on this question, one remark I think relevant is: the set $A_m$ is not uniformly bounded. To see this, for each $f\in A_m$, and each $c\in\mathbb{R}$, $f+c\in A_m$. Thus, $A_m$ is not uniformly bounded (nor is it compact, either). Moreover, I'd believe its rather extraordinary to find a family of functions in $C[0,1]$ that is equicontinuous and uniformly bounded. So, more often than not, I'd asume this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $h$. $f\to  \inf_{x\in [0,1-\frac 1 m]} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)} h $ is a continuous function on $C[0,1]$. This is a fairly strightforward verification. [Let me know if you need help with this]. Hence $\{f\in C[0,1]:\inf_{x\in [0,1-\frac 1 m]} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)} h \leq m$ is a closed set. Take intersection over $h$ to see that $A_m$ is closed.